# Update pandas dataframe columns based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['Application','Application','Hardware'],
                    'Category': ['None','None','Hardware']})
```

I have the following index to retrieve rows where type contains "application" and Category contains 'None'.

```
df1[df1['Type'].str.contains('Application') & df1['Category'].str.contains('None')]

Category    Type
0   None    Application
1   None    Application
```

I would like to update the column Category such that the value is 'some new value' for each row.

I have also tried the same with the following loc index with no success

```
df1[df1.loc[:,'Type'].str.contains('Application') \
  & df1.loc[:,'Category'].str.contains('None')]
```

Comment: Please include an example of the expected output. Also, confirm that "None" is a string, not the Python `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
df1.loc[(df1['Type'] == 'Application') & (df1['Category'] == 'None'), 'Category'] = 'New category'


    Category        Type
0   New category    Application
1   New category    Application
2   Hardware        Hardware
```

Comment: kindly using `df.loc[(df['Type'].str.contains('Application')) & (df['Category'].str.contains('None')), 'Category'] = 'New category'` maybe the column not exactly same. ~